# How can i set lat And long tude in Location manually?

Tags: java, android

I'd tried to set the latitude And longitude manually in application 
But, after run get me an error

**Code**

```
public class Common {

    public static Location NewYork;
}
```

**Configuration**

```
public void setLocation(){
    Common.NewYork.setLatitude(31.963158);  //error in this Line <--
    Common.NewYork.setLongitude(35.930359);
   fragmentAdapter();
}
```

**Error**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.location.Location.setLatitude(double)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. Also, please create a [mcve]

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.location.Location.setLatitude(double)' on a null object reference

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You never initialized the `NewYork` variable, so it is set to null when `setLocation()` is called. You can change this by doing:

```
public class Common {
    // Create new Location with an empty provider name, it's not necessary here
    public static Location NewYork = new Location(""); 
}
```

OR

```
public void setLocation() {
    Common.NewYork = new Location(""); 
    ...
}
```